# Importing AutoCAD 2017 file into QGIS/Google Earth

Tags: qgis-3, autocad

I have a map available in specific coordinates (2D) in AutoCAD 2017.

How do I import it into QGIS 3.8.3/Google Earth for data analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Importing to QGIS is easy as long as you know in which coordinates you've drawn in AutoCAD. What I mean by that is that it is preferable to work with absolute coordinates and you must have drawn **in relation to the absolute zero of the projection** (which would probably result in the points of your drawing having very long numbers for x and y).
That said, I'd rather **export from AutoCAD as .dxf** and import into QGIS the same way you would import a shapefile (be careful with the coordinates systems). To check if there's any incongruence you can **turn off the on-the-fly reprojection of layers in QGIS**.

You can follow the steps in [this tutorial](https://www.cursosgis.com/qgis-y-cad-transformaciones-y-reproyecciones/) even though it is about reprojecting layers and in Spanish (but that shouldn't be a problem with Google's on-the-fly translator).